# Angular 4 Operator to add element in beginning of array and return array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Add the element to beginning of the array and returns the array as well. this is what i am looking for in typescript.I am using angular with redux and looking to write the reducer function which demands this solution. I cannot use unshift as it does not returns the arry and even tries splice(0,0,newObject) - doesn't work. Any other idea, help. concat does the work but adds to last of the array.

```
function Addrow(state:State,action:any):State{
 return Object.assign({}, state,{

displayCodes: { list: copyobject.list.concat(state.displayCodes.list.length)},



filteredCodes: { list:copyobject.list.concat(state.displayCodes.list.length)}
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method that will add an element to the beginning of the array and return the array.

Using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) *should* work, I'd recommend trying it again:

```
function Addrow(state:State,action:any): State {
  const length = state.displayCodes.list.length;
  const list = copyobject.list.splice(0, 0, length);

  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    displayCodes: { list },
    filteredCodes: { list }
  });
}
```

You can also use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), just not as a one-liner.

```
function Addrow(state:State,action:any): State {
  const length = state.displayCodes.list.length;
  const list = copyobject.list; 
  list.unshift(length);

  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    displayCodes: { list },
    filteredCodes: { list }
  });
}
```